# Program that uploads local file to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a huge `.csv` file that I need to upload to SQL Server, so that I can access the data directly in Microsoft Power BI.

I am trying to create a program that when run will automatically put the specified file onto the server, so that the file stays updated.

What is the proper way to go about this?

I am not used to Visual Studio and C# but have tried a method like the following without success, since I don't know how to specify the SQL Server database that I have created:

```
public static void databaseFilePut(string varFilePath) 
{
    byte[] file;

    using (var stream = new FileStream(varFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream)) 
    {
        file = reader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);       
    }          

    using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
    using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raporty (RaportPlik) Values(@File)", varConnection)) 
    {
        sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
        sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help since I have been stuck at this for some time!

Thank you so much

Comment: why load into SQL Server? PowerBI can consume a .CSV file directly

Comment: I know, but I want to use Power BI Service and as far as I know if the local file is changed, you have to re-upload the file to BI Service to update the data. Or am I wrong?

Comment: To update data, you will have to reload your Power BI model in any case - regardless if it's stored in a SQL server or in a local file. The only exception to this requirement is Direct Query Mode, but it has so many disadvanatges that it's hard to justify its use (unless you have billions of records). The only other reason to use SQL Server instead of direct import is if you plan to perform complex data transformations and validations. SQLS is better for that than Power Query (tool Power BI uses to handle data imports).

Comment: I agreed with @RADO - up to the bit about data transformations. Power Query (Query Editor in Power BI) is much easier to learn and use and more flexible than SQL (or SSIS).

Comment: If your "huge .csv file" is stored in a cloud storage service (e.g. OneDrive) then Power BI web service's dataset refresh can read it directly from there, running your transformation Power Queries against it.  Then only data movement is from cloud storage service into Power BI web service dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The import work should be done through SSIS (Sql Serve Integration Services). Power BI can do the job, but consider that other 500MB you should consider using enterprise level software like SSIS.

Then once you have got all the data on your database you should build your model on SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Services) and then connect power BI for reports with live connection. The advantage of this solution is that all data is on the server, so you don't need to refresh data.

If you want **SSIS** is the enterprise level for **Power query**, and **SSAS** the enterprise level for modelling your data.

If you are familiar with modelling data in power BI and playing with DAX then you won't have too much problem dealing with SSAS, instead SSIS is quite different from the importing tool of power BI (aka Power query). Install data-tools for visual studio this is a must to work with SSIS and SSAS.

Hope that helps.